# Why does a previous SharePoint workflow instance still run?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow

SharePoint newbie here.

I have been working on a list on SharePoint online that has a simple workflow.

Due to requirement changes, I did some changes to the workflow and published it. However, when a new item is created it still runs on a old workflow instance (Previous version?).

Does anyone know why it doesn't automatically run on the latest version?

Comment: I am currently doing test in my environment and will give an update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double publish the workflow and compare the results, if the issue still exists, check the following:

If it is SharePoint 2010 whether there is previous version workflow:

[image]

If it is SharePoint 2013 platform workflow, I would suggest you recreate the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether versioning is enabled for the Workflow (wfsvc) library in SharePoint **Online** where the workflows are stored.
For details, visit [SharePoint-201-workflow-hidden-library](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sposupport/2017/10/13/troubleshooting-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow-hidden-library/)